# I can't start a C# program in Visual Studio Code although I installed all resources needed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, game-development

I am a beginner game maker; I installed unity and start learning from tutorials how to make a game. When I wanted to write a script, I found that it doesn't work and I had to launch C# in VS Code to begin programming.

From the tutorials, I learned that I have to install some extensions in VS Code and of course the .NET Framework SDK.

I get this error:

> The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
>
> - You intended to execute a .NET application:
>   The application 'restore' does not exist.
>   You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
>
> No .NET SDKs were found.
>
> Download a .NET SDK: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
>
> Learn about SDK resolution: https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

But the problem is: I installed .NET SDK and many extensions in Visual Studio Code like:

[all extensions I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO1bM.png)

[this is the result when I start my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPSGK.png)

When I start my script in unity, this happened:

[this is the result after clicking at "show erorr"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL7RG.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtGrk.png

My VS Code version is 1.85 and my .NET SDK is 8.1. I watched many tutorials, but in vain

Comment: What ```dotnet --info``` says in your command line?

Comment: then im guessing you actually didnt install the sdk you thought you should..

Comment: @Jivopis that's what said commmend line : global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.21
  Architecture: x86
  Commit:       e40b3abf1b

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Comment: @Jivopis ,   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info

Comment: @KOUSay You answered your question. You have installed .NET runtimes, not SDK-s. You need to make sutre that you install SDK package, not runtime.

Answer (score 2):

For programming with Unity in Visual Studio Code, there are a few essential extensions that can significantly enhance your development experience:

1. C# - This extension, powered by OmniSharp, provides IntelliSense,
   debugging, and other essential services for C# development. It's a
   must-have for writing and understanding C# code.
2. Debugger for Unity - This allows you to debug your Unity game
   projects directly within VS Code. You can set breakpoints, inspect
   variables, and step through your code.
3. Unity Tools - This extension adds various utilities specific to
   Unity development, like quickly opening Unity documentation or
   running Unity methods from the command palette.
4. Unity Code Snippets - With this extension, you can quickly insert
   common code snippets into your scripts, which can speed up
   development for common tasks and function implementations.
5. Unity Snippets - This is another snippet extension that provides a
   collection of snippets for Unity scripting, which can help you write
   more code with fewer keystrokes.
6. .NET Core Test Explorer - If you're planning to write unit tests for
   your Unity game (which is a good practice), this extension will help
   you run and debug tests right from the editor.

Make sure to also configure VS Code to use the correct version of the .NET framework that corresponds with your version of Unity for the best compatibility.

Hope help this answer for you